# Calculating pairwise distances for Shapely geometry objects

Tags: python, scikit-learn, geopandas

I'm asking this on regular stackoverflow instead of stackexchange GIS because my problem is more with scikit-learn than with any GIS-related libraries.

I have a GeoDataFrame (A Pandas GeoDataFrame but with additional functionalities for geometry) containing polygons and I want to calculate the pairwise distances between them. I am also working with scikit-learn and it seems that they have some nice optimized functions for this, and it also seems that you can specify a callable function to do the actual distance calculate, which is nice because then I can (I think) just use Shapely's `.distance()` method to get the distance between the polygons when outputting the distance matrix. This method calculates the geometric distance between two geometries.

I can't figure out how to implement the custom callable function, however. This is what I have so far:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from random import uniform
from shapely.geometry import Point
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

# Define polygon to polygon distance callable
def poly_distance(poly1, poly2):
    return poly1.distance(poly2)

# Make some points and buffer them into polygons
geoms = [Point(uniform(0, 100), uniform(0, 100)) for i in range(100)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geoms, columns=["geometry"], geometry="geometry")
gdf[gdf.geometry.name] = gdf.buffer(1)

X = gdf[gdf.geometry.name].to_numpy()

result = pairwise_distances(X, poly_distance)
```

I thought that this would work because I am specifying a function which will take two elements from the resultant numpy array (`X`) and return a float distance between them. But it complains:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Polygon'
```

The [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances) do indeed say:

> The callable should take two arrays from X as input and return a value indicating the distance between them.

But I don't know how to get it into this format that the function wants. I also tried the following definitions of `X`:

```
X = np.array([gdf[gdf.geometry.name].to_numpy()])
X = np.transpose(np.array([gdf[gdf.geometry.name].to_numpy()]))
```

But neither of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sklearn metrics expect the argument `x` to have valid dtype which is convertible to float. If you see the source code it converts the array to float before computing the distances between them.

Since your X consists of a polygon object, you get an error while converting the array to float.

However, you can build your own `pair_wise` function which takes `polygon array` and `distance function` as input and give `distance matrix` as output.

**Code:**

```
import geopandas as gpd
from random import uniform
from shapely.geometry import Point
import numpy as np

# Define polygon to polygon distance callable
def poly_distance(poly1, poly2):
    return poly1.distance(poly2)

# Make some points and buffer them into polygons
geoms = [Point(uniform(0, 100), uniform(0, 100)) for i in range(100)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geoms, columns=["geometry"], geometry="geometry")
gdf[gdf.geometry.name] = gdf.buffer(1)
X = gdf[gdf.geometry.name].to_numpy()

def pair_wise(x, function):
  distance_matrix = []
  for element in x:
    distance_matrix.append([function(element, item) for item in x])
  return np.array(distance_matrix)

pair_wise(X, poly_distance)
```

Comment: Rather slow unfortunately, which is why I was hoping I could use something from sklearn, because I was hoping to use some of its internal optimization. But it does technically work.